# Route middleware in ExpressJs?

Tags: express

I am new at ExpressJs. so I have some questions about middlewares. So,when do we have to use route middleware in ExpressJs?

Answer (score 0):

First off middleware is code that generally operates on a number of incoming requests.  For example, you might have some middleware that checks a cookie to see if this request is authorized before allowing routing to other request handlers to continue. If the request is authorized, it would call `next()` to continue routing to whatever route handles that specific URL.  If the request is not authorized, then it would send an error response and stop further routing.  There are thousands of possible uses for middleware - authorization checking is just one such example.

So, you would use middleware when you have multiple routes that all want some sort of pre-check or pre-processing done before the individual routes get called.

Since you asked about "route middleware", perhaps you also wanted to know when you would use middleware on a specific router rather than on the `app` object.  That would be the same when you want middleware to apply only to the routes that are directed to a router object, not on all routes.  That can also be done by specifying a path for the middleware such that is only gets called for certain paths.

Answer (score 0):

You can use middlewares when you want to filter your requests before it goes to the next step and make an operation that you want to do there. For e.g in following ways you can have make use of middewares:

1. Validate
2. Authorization
3. Access levels
4. Restrict requests calls